# Panel window in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am used to Adobe flex. In action script, we could create a new panel window by using the new keyword and pop it up using popups. We could customize the window by using the functions provided in the Panel class.  Is there any way we can perform the same kind of action in angular 4? I want to have a customised window which i can popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show some extra information with pop up in any of your page then angular bootstrap will good for you. It currently supports Angular 5 and Bootstrap 4, but you can give it a try with angular 2/4. Please check below link to install it into your current angular project.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

After successful installation just select **Modal** from right side or use below link. You can use these Modals to show required information in your angular project.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

If you want to pop out a new window/tab in the browser then you can use below native JS function.

window.open()